# AWS Cloudfromation and autoscaling : The requested configuration is currently not supported. Launching EC2 instance failed

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, autoscaling

I want to replicate the infrastructure from one region(us-east-1) to another(us-east-2). so,I have generated a cloudfromation template of an existing infrastructure with the help of cloudformer tool.

```
    "asgamazonecsclisetupapijoulebugprodEcsInstanceAsg1EIBNOXSXJ7HD": {
  "Type": "AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup",
  "Properties": {
    "AvailabilityZones": [
      "us-east-2b",
      "us-east-2c"
    ],
    "Cooldown": "300",
    "DesiredCapacity": "3",
    "HealthCheckGracePeriod": "300",
    "HealthCheckType": "ELB",
    "MaxSize": "16",
    "MinSize": "3",
    "VPCZoneIdentifier": [
      {
        "Ref": "subnet81c8ebab"
      },
      {
        "Ref": "subnet5df40214"
      }
    ],
    "LaunchConfigurationName": {
      "Ref": "lcamazonecsclisetupapijoulebugprodAMI2017d"
    },
    "LoadBalancerNames": [
      {

        "Ref": "elbJBAPILiveCleanbit2016"
      }
    ],
    "Tags": [
      {
        "Key": "Name",
        "Value": "Live - Cleanbit2016 - joulebug-api",
        "PropagateAtLaunch": true
      }
    ],
    "TerminationPolicies": [
      "Default"
    ]
  }
},
"lcamazonecsclisetupapijoulebugprodAMI2017d": {
  "Type": "AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration",
  "Properties": {
    "AssociatePublicIpAddress": true,
    "ImageId": "ami-0e6d83442546978bc",
    "InstanceType": "c3.large",
    "KeyName": "cleanbit2016_vpc",
    "IamInstanceProfile": "amazon-ecs-cli-setup-api-joulebug-prod-EcsInstanceProfile-1M4GOHBP3FP5L",
    "InstanceMonitoring": "true",
    "SecurityGroups": [
      {
        "Ref": "sgCleanbit2016WebServerSG"
      }
    ],
    "BlockDeviceMappings": [
      {
        "DeviceName": "/dev/xvda",
        "Ebs": {
          "SnapshotId": "snap-0b2477be9c863d014",
          "VolumeSize": 8
        }
      },
      {
        "DeviceName": "/dev/xvdcz",
        "Ebs": {
          "VolumeSize": 22
        }
      }
    ]
  }
},
"elbJBAPILiveCleanbit2016": {
  "Type": "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancing::LoadBalancer",
  "Properties": {
    "Policies": [
      {
        "PolicyName": "AWSConsole-SSLNegotiationPolicy-JB-API-Live-Cleanbit2016-1467998170471",
        "PolicyType": "SSLNegotiationPolicyType",
          }
    ],
    }
    }
    "subnet81c8ebab": {
  "Type": "AWS::EC2::Subnet",
  "Properties": {
    "CidrBlock": "10.0.3.0/24",
    "AvailabilityZone": "us-east-2b",
    "VpcId": {
      "Ref": "vpcdcbd08bb"
    },
    "Tags": [
      {
        "Key": "Name",
        "Value": "Cleanbit2016 - Public 1b"
      }
    ]
  }
},
 "sgCleanbit2016WebServerSG": {
  "Type": "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
  "Properties": {
    "GroupDescription": "Web server security group for public subnet in vpc.",
    "VpcId": {
      "Ref": "vpcdcbd08bb"
    },
    "Tags": [
      {
        "Key": "Name",
        "Value": "Cleanbit2016_ WebServerSG"
      }
    ]
  }
},
```

While launching the template in other region(us-east-2), it is throwing following error:

The requested configuration is currently not supported. Please check the documentation for supported configurations. Launching EC2 instance failed.

Comment: Is `subnet81c8ebab` defined elsewhere in your template? That looks similar to a Subnet ID, which would be different each time it is created.

Comment: Yes, It is defined in my template file.

Comment: I tried your solution then, it is throwing error : Autoscaling group and subnets do not match.

Comment: Could you please update your question to show either the full template, or at least all elements referenced by the above?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein: I have edited my Question.Please let me know if you want some more code.

Comment: Please include the portion that defines the security group `sgCleanbit2016WebServerSG`.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein: added the security group sgCleanbit2016WebServerSG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of debugging, when I started launching the things manually, I found the same error and I got to know that c3.large is causing the error. When I launch the template with c4.large it successfully launched the template from us-east-1 to us-east-2.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have details of the regions you're using, but if you are trying to do this outside of us-east-1 the Availablility Zones won't work.  It also looks like you have a number of other parts of the stack hard-coded, which may not work in another region.

And if you are trying to do this in us-east-1, there is the possibility that one of the AZs is unavailable to you - see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21390444/is-there-a-way-for-cloudformation-to-query-available-zones-for-subnet-creation) for more details.

Comment: I am trying to launch template from us-east-1 to us-east-2, before making this change hardcoded, I checked the available regions also. It is throwing error while generating the Autoscaling groups. The templates generate the few ec2 instances successfully in that region.

Answer (score 1):

You have not provided enough information to be able to diagnose the situation.

I took your template, removed the portions that were incomplete (eg removed the Load Balancer because it was missing Listeners), simplified a few things and it works fine:

```
{
    "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
    "Resources": {
        "VPC": {
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::VPC",
            "Properties": {
                "CidrBlock": "10.0.0.0/16",
                "Tags": [
                    {
                        "Key": "Name",
                        "Value": "Lab VPC"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "ASG": {
            "Type": "AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup",
            "Properties": {
                "AvailabilityZones": [
                    "us-east-2b",
                    "us-east-2c"
                ],
                "Cooldown": "300",
                "DesiredCapacity": "1",
                "HealthCheckGracePeriod": "300",
                "MaxSize": "16",
                "MinSize": "1",
                "VPCZoneIdentifier": [
                    {
                        "Ref": "Subnet1"
                    },
                    {
                        "Ref": "Subnet2"
                    }
                ],
                "LaunchConfigurationName": {
                    "Ref": "LaunchConfig"
                }
            }
        },
        "LaunchConfig": {
            "Type": "AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration",
            "Properties": {
                "AssociatePublicIpAddress": true,
                "ImageId": "ami-0b59bfac6be064b78",
                "InstanceType": "t2.micro",
                "InstanceMonitoring": "true",
                "SecurityGroups": [
                    {
                        "Ref": "WebServerSG"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "Subnet1": {
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::Subnet",
            "Properties": {
                "CidrBlock": "10.0.0.0/24",
                "AvailabilityZone": "us-east-2b",
                "VpcId": {
                    "Ref": "VPC"
                },
                "Tags": [
                    {
                        "Key": "Name",
                        "Value": "Public 1"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "Subnet2": {
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::Subnet",
            "Properties": {
                "CidrBlock": "10.0.1.0/24",
                "AvailabilityZone": "us-east-2c",
                "VpcId": {
                    "Ref": "VPC"
                },
                "Tags": [
                    {
                        "Key": "Name",
                        "Value": "Public 2"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "WebServerSG": {
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
            "Properties": {
                "GroupDescription": "Web server security group for public subnet in vpc.",
                "VpcId": {
                    "Ref": "VPC"
                },
                "Tags": [
                    {
                        "Key": "Name",
                        "Value": "WebServerSG"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Therefore, your problem lies in part of the template you did *not* provide.

You could start with this version, then progressively add back parts of your template until you discover what is causing the error.

Comment: Thank you so much.Let me check this, I will get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to create a CloudFormation template that can run in multiple regions, you should not refer to specific Availability Zones (eg `us-east-2b`).

You can use [Fn::GetAZs - AWS CloudFormation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-getavailabilityzones.html) to obtain a list of AZs in region.

Comment: I need to launch that template in us-east-2 region only.